# Testing IPad app with GDB hangs with black screen, fine on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

I have an app built on iOS 4.2, which works fine on the simulator. When I build and run the app on the device it hangs. The only way to wake it up is to kill GDB (i.e. hit the red stop sign). As long as GDB isn't running the app runs fine. I can open it up from the spring board and test as normal. Although if GDB is still running, and I launch the app from the spring board, the black screen just comes up again.

I don't have any breakpoints, and have Visible at Launch and Full Screen at Launch checked on my MainWindow.xib.

I get the same behaviour on my iPhone as well.

There's something about debugging on the device that just makes it just show a black screen. Although, I can see the status bar.

I've checked the GDB logs, but most just warn me about a device/SDK mismatch between some of the frameworks. Eg:

> warning: UUID mismatch detected with
>   the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
>   warning: UUID mismatch detected with
>   the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
>   warning: UUID mismatch detected with
>   the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
>   warning: UUID mismatch detected with
>   the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
>   warning: UUID mismatch detected with
>   the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: What OS is the device running?

Comment: Im assuming you mean version? The iPad has 4.2 (8C134b), and the iPhone has 4.0.2 (8A400)

Comment: Have you tried pausing the execution with the visual debugger to see if the app is perhaps stuck in a loop in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my SDK and the device with the latest versions from Apple and it seemed to fix this issue.